# .htaccess problme in codeigniter for removing index.php from url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have `.htaccess`  file in my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

If i use
`http://iemedica.com.ph/index.php/aboutUs` it will working for me
 but if  i use
`http://iemedica.com.ph/aboutUs` its give me `404` Error

Comment: Do you have the mod_rewrite module enabled in Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Change your .htaccess to ths:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Also in `DocumentRoot/application/config/config.php` you need to have these config settings:

```
$config['base_url']     = '';
$config['index_page']   = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: Did you apply changes in `/application/config/config.php` also? Is CI running in `DocumentRoot` or in some subdir?

Comment: Yes i apply changes also and Ci Running in Document Root Dir.

Comment: ok try: `$config['uri_protocol'] = 'QUERY_STRING';` in your `DocumentRoot/application/config/config.php`

Comment: Do you have some other rules or this is full .htaccess? Also is there a .htaccess inside `/application/` folder also?

Comment: In /application/ folder there is .htaccess file but it empty

Comment: Remove `/application/.htaccess` and retest.

Comment: Same problem as i tray same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67319/discussion-between-anubhava-and-amol-challawar).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do the following changes in application->config->config.php

```
             $config['base_url'] = "";
             $config['index_page'] = "";
```

While in .htaccess write the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

This will work.

Comment: @amolchallawar copy the above .htaccess code and put it in your .htaccess

Comment: @amolchallawar your url must be like this site_name/controller_name/method_name

Comment: i am using url rewriting in my routing file like 
$route['aboutUs'] = "pages/aboutUs";

Comment: @amolchallawar i modify the last line of .htaccess in the above code try it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable your Rewrite module in Apache server and use this HTA Access

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

copy and paste this code and save the file in the name of .htaccess under your codeigniter directory.